# CMake add_custom_target: Ninja suppressing output until command completed and therefore user interaction not possible

Tags: cmake, ninja

If I add

```
add_custom_target(dummy COMMAND dir && sleep 2)
```

And then

```
ninja dummy
```

The directory content is visualized only after the sleep is terminated. I understand that this mechanism has a valuable property that is to allow Ninja to show a very neat/sequential output even while executing several jobs in parallel.

However, this is a problem in the following practical case: my real `add_custom_target` would execute a program that at some point will prompt the user asking for a password, but Ninja basically blocks any interaction.

Is there a workaround for this?

Note: Using `-v` option (verbose) doesn't help, and also `-j 1` (only one job at a time).

**Another example:**

```
add_custom_target(dummy COMMAND cmd /c time)
```

And:

```
D:\build> ninja dummy
[1/1] cmd.exe /c cd D:\build && cmd /c time
FAILED: cmd.exe /c cd D:\build && cmd /c time
The current time is: 13:06:08.57
Enter the new time: ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

**Some hints:**
*[ninja-build > Launching interactive apps from build rules](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ninja-build/prompt/ninja-build/gJ3Z-_SFiYk/U4q3CiO7gb4J)*

Answer (score 1):

I got feedback from the Ninja mailing list.

There's an issue on this topic, and a patch (although I am not sure if by not caching it will also allow interaction; given the outcome of the test with `time`, probably not):

[Issue](https://github.com/martine/ninja/issues/545).
[Patch](https://github.com/maximuska/ninja/commit/ceecafb72ab5d57831a99c43bd64c581f2098ca2).

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the design of Ninja.

Related issue: *[0014544: Remove edit_cache target from ninja output](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14544)*

Comment: Hi! Can you go a little bit more in detail explaining how that issue is related?